# want to print half submenu of a parent menu out of total

Tags: html, for-loop, menu, submenu

I called menu bar from admin, I want print sub-menu of a parent menu, I have total 20 sub-menu but I wanna print 10 sub-menu on parent menu hover. Code here...

```
<?php

$defaults = array(
'theme_location'  => '',
'menu'            => 'menu',
'container'       => 'div',
'container_class' => '',
'container_id'    => '',
'menu_class'      => 'menu',
'menu_id'         => '',
'echo'            => true,
'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
'before'          => '',
'after'           => '',
'link_before'     => '',
'link_after'      => '',
'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
'depth'           => 0,
'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```

Comment: What code have you tried already?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sorry I have no idea, I know just looping can do it.